# Creating a socket inside a thread C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets

I've been given a problem to solve... heres how it goes:

I'm required to write two programs, client and server.

My client program is going to do some trivial task X, which creates a queue of size N.

Then the client program will create N threads, and these child threads will each create a socket, and send some information pertaining to X to the server.

The server then receives this information from the client, and creates child processes to further process this information, and send it back to the client.

My main question is how to go about creating the socket INSIDE the thread.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define NTHREADS 5

void *process_X(void *x_void_ptr)
{
    //random
    //do i create the socket here?
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
static int x = 0;
pthread_t tid[NTHREADS];

for(int i=0;i<NTHREADS;i++)
{
    if(pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, inc_x, &x)) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error creating thread\n");
        return 1;

    }       
}
// Wait for the other threads to finish.
 for (int i = 0; i < NTHREADS; i++)
        pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
 return 0;
}
```

Also, in the information I've been given about creating sockets, i will be inputting hostname and port number from command line. So I will need to use argv[] too, so I dont know how to do that, if it wont be in the main function.

Any help greatly appreciated...

Comment: Same way you create any other socket in any other context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My main question is how to go about creating the socket INSIDE the thread.

Everything within your `process_X` function takes place in the new thread. So, you do indeed create the socket where your comment indicates.

> So I will need to use argv[] too, so I dont know how to do that, if it wont be in the main function.

The last parameter of `pthread_create` is passed on into `process_X`, which is what `x_void_ptr` is. You can simply cast `x_void_ptr` to whatever type you need it to be.

I suggest parsing the CLI arguments in your `main` function, and arranging the data in a `struct`, which is then passed into `process_X` via `pthread_create`.

Comment: this is exactly what i was hoping for in a reply.
do you mind writing some.. pseudocode for the last part of your answer? parsing cli arguments into main function?

Comment: `argv` is going to contain strings. You can probably use the hostname as a string just fine (I'm a bit rusty on BSD sockets) to create a socket, but this won't work for the port. To convert a string to an integer, you would use `atoi` from `cstdlib`.

Comment: I believe in my socket code i will have the following:
    port_number = atoi(argv[2]); 
    server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
you're saying I should create a struct containing these two to pass through pthread_create?

Comment: Yes, `pthread_create` only allows you to pass a single argument, not multiple. Therefore, we need a struct as a workaround.